# AsyncTask Implementation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application, i need to reduce the time of inserting videos and other details from the database. I'm trying to use the AsyncTask concept in my application. But it gives an error in my insertion part when i do it in doInBackground().Another class does the insertion.

abc.insert(arguments);
where abc is the object of my database class.

Error shown is nullpointerexception in my class where insertion is done.

Is there any solution for  this?

thanks,

niki

Comment: Some code would really help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully get your case, but it sounds like your are a victim of synchronization issue - several Threads are calling your insertion code.

If this is the case, then a simle solutions is to use Java `synchronized` statement around your insertion code, e.g.:

```
public synchronized void insert() { /* code to insert */ }
```

or

```
private Object lock = new Object(); // a field of your DBHelper

// somewhere below in your DBHelper
synchronized (lock) {
     /* code to insert */
}
```

Comment: Then I we just can not guess - please share your both the code and the LogCat output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to add data to your database in a worker thread with no UI update post addition then use Java Threads insted of AsynTask.

The sole objective of AsyncTask is to perform the expensive operations in background and update UI after the operation has been performed.

As suggested by Arhimed the database locking can be an issue in your case if you have fired multiple AsyncTasks.